# emoji picker in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, emoji

I´m working in a chat system and I would like implement an emoji picker in my input field text.. I have installed lookback:emoji package and right now it working fine with simple ASCII conversion. For example if I type :), the package works and I can see the smile emoji right. But I want also choose "manually" from a picker the emojis, but I can´t find a solution...
I´m looking for something like Slack emoji picker... I have take a look also to www.emojione.com project but I didn´t find any help... I thought that´s was a common issue, but I don´t find any useful info about it....
Some suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: since you have a collection, wouldn't you just be able to run a query and display all the emojis and paginate it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sdybskiy. Yes, this is an option, but I think that´s not trivial create from scratch an emoji picker (like slack for example)... I can work on pagination, but I must also work with javascript (events,helpers, some jquery...) I was looking for some package or plugin instead of create the whole picker... Thanks again!

Comment: @Cos, sadly I did not find anything... I was working at the moment in my chat with loockback:emoji, but it works only one with ASCII conversion. It means that when you type ":)" the emoji appear, but I cant choose my emojis from a picker...:( . Let me know if you find something please!;)